# Dealing with error when making fetch call in redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm building a weather app that returns weather details for a particular city. Everything works fine when a valid location is entered. My problem occurs when I enter a junk string (ex. 'afasdfldsakfh') into the search field and press enter. This makes sense as the api call should not find the location.

I get the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'observation_location' of undefined
```

This is coming from the reducer under the RECEIVE_WEATHER case. I'm not sure what I need to do when the payload is not valid and missing the info I need to set the props for my state. Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
export function receiveWeather(json) {
  console.log(json);
  return {
    type: RECEIVE_WEATHER,
    payload: json
  };
};

export function fetchingWeather(location) {
  const init = {
    method: 'GET'
  };
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(requestWeather())
    return fetch(weatherUrl + location + '.json', init)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => dispatch(receiveWeather(json)))
  };  
};

export function weather(state = {
  isFetching: false,
  city: '',
  country: '',
  weather_image: '',
  weather_description: '',
  weather_number: '',
  wind_dir: '',
  wind_speed: '',
  humidity: '',
  precipitation: ''
}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case REQUEST_WEATHER:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isFetching: true
      });
    case RECEIVE_WEATHER:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isFetching: false,
        city: (action.payload.current_observation.observation_location.full),
        country: (action.payload.current_observation.observation_location.country),
        weather_image: (action.payload.current_observation.icon_url),
        weather_description: (action.payload.current_observation.weather),
        weather_number: (action.payload.current_observation.temp_c),
        wind_dir: (action.payload.current_observation.wind_dir),
        wind_speed: (action.payload.current_observation.wind_kph),
        humidity: (action.payload.current_observation.relative_humidity),
        precipitation: (action.payload.current_observation.precip_today_in)
      });
    default:
      return state
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your fetch call use attach an error handler like so:

```
return fetch(weatherUrl + location + '.json', init)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => dispatch(receiveWeather(json)))
  .catch(err => handleError(err))
```

I don't know what implementation of `fetch` you're using but there's generally a `catch` or `error` method on the api.

You can also add a case that handles the error as such:

```
case RECEIVE_WEATHER_ERROR: 
   return ...
```

and in that case you may as well dispatch the error in the error handler

```
return fetch(weatherUrl + location + '.json', init)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => dispatch(receiveWeather(json)))
  .catch(err => dispatch(handleError(err)))
```

`handleError` can be implemented just like your other functions:

```
function handleError(err) {
  return {
    type: RECEIVE_WEATHER_ERROR,
    payload: err
  }
}
```

If you're not getting an error back but instead an empty json object where `payload.current_observation` is undefined

In your case statement add the following:

```
case RECEIVE_WEATHER:
  if (!action.payload.current_observation) return state
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply JoshSGman. I don't see my implementation of fetch in my package.json file. However, I do see 'whatwg-fetch' in my node_modules folder. I'm using this react skeleton: https://github.com/joellongie/dustDevil. I can't seem to get to the handleError function after I add the '.catch(err...' line. I tried console.log('hello') before the return and I got nothing.

Comment: @Banner Try `.error(err => dispatch(handleError(err))` instead of .catch

Comment: Getting this in the console: Uncaught TypeError: fetch(...).then(...).then(...).error is not a function

Comment: @Banner I looked into the `whatwg-fetch` module, looks like `.catch` is the way to go. Where are you putting your `console.log`?

Comment: .catch now returns the original error. The console.log is in the handleError function. I put it there to see if I can get there. Thanks for all your help so far!

Comment: importing fetch like this: import 'whatwg-fetch';

Comment: @Banner, the original error being what?

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'observation_location' of undefined` ? 

It's possible that you're not getting an error back, but instead you're getting an empty json object. If that's the case, just put an if statement somewhere that just returns the current state if `action.payload.current_observation == undefined`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123388/discussion-between-joshsgman-and-banner).